# RegEx to remove single quote, parentheses or square bracket from both beginning and end of a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net-2010

I want to remove single quote, parentheses and square brackets from the beginning and end of a string using regEx. 
Eg.

1. 'My name' - should change to My name.
2. [My name] -  should change to My name.
3. (My name) - should change to My name.
4. '([My name])' - should change to My name.
5. ('My name]' - should change to My name.(Should remove all ',(,) ,[ or ] irrespective of its order)
6. My n'am]e - should be My n'am]e (**should not remove ', (,) , [ or ] if its not at the beginning or end of string**)
7. ''([[[(My name)]]])'' - should be My name (number of ',() or [] can be any and all should be removed).

Please help me to create a regEx for doing all these tasks at once.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: What about `[MyName])` or `[[MyName]`, should they become `MyName)` and `[MyName`?

Comment: In all these cases, the output should be MyName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
s/^['\[(]*(.*)['\](]*$/$1/
```

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't quite work as is. The .* should be non-greedy and you need a closing parenthesis in the last character set. Something like this: ^['\[(]*(.*?)['\])]*$.

Comment: Nothing is worked for me

Answer (score 3):

You don't *need* regular expressions for this.  [`string.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx) is the best implementation of the "*number of ',() or [] can be any and all should be removed*" requirement and test #5.

```
var cleaned = dirty.Trim("'()[]".ToCharArray());
```

---

With some tests:

```
const string expected = "My name";

Func<string, string> clean = given => given.Trim("'()[]".ToCharArray());

Assert.AreEqual(expected, clean("'My name'"));
Assert.AreEqual(expected, clean("[My name]"));
Assert.AreEqual(expected, clean("(My name)"));
Assert.AreEqual(expected, clean("'([My name])'"));
Assert.AreEqual(expected, clean("('My name]'"));
Assert.AreEqual(expected, clean("''([[[(My name)]]])''"));
Assert.AreEqual("My n'am]e", clean("My n'am]e"));
```